# Avoid calling nested method two times

Tags: ruby

For a given file name path, I need to get the folder one level before it. This can be accomplished in ruby with the following code:

```
File.dirname(File.dirname("/a/b/c.txt"))
 => "/a"
```

Independently from this exact case, how can I DRY two method calls in sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider any DRYing efforts in terms of its effects on code clarity. I don't think that trying to reduce `foo(foo(bar))` is worth the reduced clarity. Now, if we're trying to reduce `foo(foo(foo(foo(foo(bar)))))`, that's something else. One way you can do that is using `reduce`:

```
5.times.reduce(1 << 64) { |x,| Math.sqrt(x) }
=> 4.0

5.times.reduce('/a/b/c/d/e/f.txt') { |x,| File.dirname(x) }
=> "/a"
```